# ZSH ZLE Widget remove accept-line command from history

Tags: zsh, history

I would like to add some additional syntax to zsh. I would like `//some/path/to/file` to be relative to the root of my source code tree (`/src/repositories/projects`). So running `ls //some/path/to/directory` should list files in `/src/repositories/projects/some/path/to/directory`.

The best way I've found to do this is with a ZLE accept-line widget which rewrites `//...` paths with the full UNIX path `/src/repositories/projects/...` and then invokes the command. This works quite well, but it expands the `//...` syntax inline and stores the expansion in history, which can make searches a bit more complicated. I would like to store the original `//...` syntax in the history while keep the `/src/repositories/projects/...` syntax out.

I am able to use `print -s` to add the original `//...` syntax to history, but I am having trouble keeping the expanded syntax out of history. Currently my code looks like this:

```
function accept-line-override() {
  # Add untranslated command to history
  print -s "$BUFFER"

  # Translate //... paths to /src/repositories/projects/...
  BUFFER=$(fix-paths "$BUFFER")

  # Invoke command with new paths
  zle .accept-line
}

zle -N accept-line accept-line-override
```

This gives me two lines of history for every invoked command:

```
$ echo //test
/src/repositories/projects/test
$ history | tail -n 2
10020  echo //test
10021  echo /src/repositories/projects/test
```

Is there a way I can prevent `zle .accept-line` from adding its command to history? I've seen methods involving `history -d` but those only seem to work for bash. I also saw somewhere to do:

```
function accept-line-override() {
  # Add untranslated command to history
  print -s "$BUFFER"

  # Translate //... paths to /src/repositories/projects/...
  BUFFER=$(fix-paths "$BUFFER")

  # Manually invoke line so it is not added to history
  echo
  eval $BUFFER
  echo

  # Reset prompt
  BUFFER=""
  zle .reset-prompt
}
```

But this leads to a lot of undesired side-effects, from Emacs refusing to open to auto-completions not clearing before the command is executed. I'd very much like to avoid that complexity if at all possible. Any idea on getting around this?

Comment: It seems to me, that you could avoid most of the issues by using Zsh's [Named Directories feature](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories) instead of replacing `//` on your own. For example: After running `hash -d some=/src/repositories/projects/some` you can use `~some/path/to/file` instead of `//some/path/to/file` and Zsh will expand it on its own to `/src/repositories/projects/some/path/to/file`. You can use `for dir in /src/repositories/projects/*(/); hash -d ${${dir##*/}// /_}=$dir` to create names for all projects.

Comment: He's already found a solution, but trying to clean up history.  Answering that the best way to x is start from somewhere else may not be helpful.  I like the warp drive zsh plugin myself.  eg wd test would bring me to /src/repositories/projects/test and life, for me, continues merrily.

Comment: @Adaephon, I was not familiar with Named Directories, that's definitely a useful feature I'll have to keep in mind for the future. However, I would very much prefer to use that `//` syntax if at all possible. Is there any way to utilize a named directory labeled `//`?